# AnsibleUndefinedVariable in template

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

i hope you guys can help me.
I want to copy following template with ansible:

```
   IFACE_EXTERNAL="{{ ansible_default_ipv4.interface }}"
   IP_EXTERNAL="{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"

   IFACE6_EXTERNAL="{{ ansible_default_ipv6.interface }}"
   IP6_EXTERNAL="{{ ansible_default_ipv6.address }}"

{% if ansible_interfaces[2] is defined %}
{% set count = 2 %}
{% for iface in ansible_interfaces %}
{% if "tun0" in iface %}
   IFACE_INTERNAL_1="{{ iface }}"
{% endif %}
{% if "ens" in iface %}
   IFACE_INTERNAL_{{count}}="{{ iface }}"
{% set count = count + 1 %}
{% endif %}
{% if hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_%s'|format(iface)]['ipv4'] is defined %}
   IP_INTERNAL_{{loop.index}}="{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_%s'|format(iface)]['ipv4']['address'] }}"

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Now, if i copy this template with ansible, i get following error: "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'interface'".
I tried for an hour but don't get a solution.
Does anyone know where the error is?

Comment: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20051#issuecomment-271891050 ?

Comment: interesting, thanks for the advise.
But i think i am to new to the linux world, i don't know how i can add another interface like in this github issue.
I have to copy this template on my testsystem before i can trie it on the final system (which has multiple interfaces)
Do you know how i can add interfaces so ansible_default_ipv4 is not empty?

Comment: I tried it now on another test machine... Well, it worked directly. idk where the error was, but it works now.
Thx for your Help!

Answer (score 1):

You wrote a very complicated jinja template. Now, live and suffer with it.

It's really bad idea to have a complicated access patterns into dynamic variables within jinja, as you have 0 (zero) debug tools there.

The proper way is to have all computation to be done at ansible level:

```yaml
tasks:
- debug: var=some_var1
- debug: var=some_var2
- template:
    src: foo.j2
    dest: foo
vars:
  some_var1: '{{...}}'
  some_var2: '{{...}}'
```

By using external (ansible) vars you can debug them. If you use computation in Jinja you need to be 100% sure data are there. How can you be sure that facts are there, if `default` set of network variables is dependent on where there is default gateway or not on the target system?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid such errors you must use something similar to `{{ ansible_default_ipv6.interface | default('foo') }}` as there is no guarantee that ansible_default_ipv6 object has the interface attribute.

If you do not do this, you will get templating errors. The other option is to use if conditions like `'{% if interface' in ansible_default_ipv6 %}...`.